# Get path name of route globally in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a basic routing SPA working using `react-router-dom v4` and I would like to get the current route (path name) for use in my header (outer context of the app - not sure if that's accurate nomenclature). I want to have a button in my app bar which will do something depending on the route currently in use.

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <div>
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <MainView />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

**header.js**

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  toggleDrawer(){
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open}, ()=> {console.log(this.state)});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar
          iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
          onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={()=>{this.toggleDrawer()}}
          iconElementRight={<FlatButton label="Create New"/>}
        />

        ...
```

In the `header.js` I want access to the route's pathname to call a certain function from the `<FlatButton />` on the right of the appbar. I've tried `{this.props.location.pathname}` as per the v4 docs but only got errors. TBH I was probably using it wrong though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That prop is only provided to components rendered as the child of a `Route`.  If you want it somewhere else (like in your Header), you can use the [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) helper method to inject the props into your component:

```
// Header.js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

// private header class
class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
      // you can access this.props.location here
   }
}

// wrap Header class in a new class that will render the
// Header class with the current location
// export this class so other classes will render this
// wrapped component
export default withRouter(Header);

// index.js
// ....
ReactDOM.render((
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <div>
      <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <MainView />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: And to access it I would call `HeaderWithRouterProps.location.pathname`? Or are they just injected into the main `props`?

Comment: As long as your page renders `HeaderWithRouterProps`, then HeaderWithRouterProps will render `Header` and pass in the props, so Header will be able to access it as `this.props.location`

Comment: Oh ok, so then `HeaderWithRouteProps` goes in the class that renders the `<Header />` component? (Sorry, I am very new to React)

Comment: yes.  Usually you just export HeaderWithRouterProps from Header.js instead of exporting Header.  Then the page layout (index.js) doesn't even need to change.

Comment: I want the route in the `<Header />` component though (I think?) in order to handle logic on the button click. If I export the `HeaderWithRouteProps` doesn't that mean that the props would then be available inside the `index.js` which I couldn't do anything with them there?

Comment: I filled in the example to hopefully make more sense.  Read about "higher order components" to learn more about the concepts in play here, but basically you are creating a component which wraps your Header, and whenever it is rendered, it collects the Route information from the React context and passes it as props to your Header component.  index.js remains unchanged.

Comment: Thanks! I admit the hierarchy was throwing me off, I was thinking it needed to be the opposite but after some reading it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You should use react-router-dom if you are not using it (it's the default react-router package for the web now).

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render((
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route component={Header} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={MainView} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

and then from the header.js try using

```
this.props.location.pathname
```

Comment: Within the `index.js`? Or move it to the `<Header />` component out of the `index.js` and into the `main.js`? I believe I did it this way for the sake of the header being always available. If I move it into the `main.js` it goes away between routes.